# Does ATS offer Multiplayer?

Tags: american-truck-simulator

I want drive around with real humans, chat, and meet other people! There's one for ETS 2 [r/Ets2mp/](http://www.reddit.com/r/ets2mp/) .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a Multiplayer mod for ETS2 and ATS : [TruckersMP](https://truckersmp.com/)

[image]

Here you can see my TruckersMP Launcher, but because I've got only ETS2, you won't see the *Launch ATS* button.

TruckersMP is a community multiplayer mod. There are plenty of players on ETS2, really less on ATS because there is no NPC cars / trucks and ATS isn't really famous next to ETS2.

How to install TruckersMP :

1. create an account on [TruckersMP website](https://truckersmp.com/) (you need to associate a valid Steam account, which own ETS2 or/and ATS)
2. download TruckersMP installer and launch it
3. select ATS Multiplayer (and ETS2 Multiplayer if you have it), and add the ATS launcher path (in my case, ETS2 launcher path is `D:\Steam\steamapps\common\Euro Truck Simulator 2`)
4. Start TruckersMP, click on the truck at bottom-left to start ATS Multiplayer (bottom-right for ETS2 Multiplayer), and enjoy

Comment: "TruckersMP is the official multiplayer platform from SCS Software" no is not, is a community mod for the game, otherwise it would be included with the game download.

Comment: @Lemon I corrected it, because some TruckersMP moderators are also from SCS Software, it's easy to do the mistake

Answer (score 1):

Since this was posted, both ATS and ETS2 now support multiplayer mode in the vanilla game, no mods needed. Check out "convoys", you can run up to 8 trucks on a server. There's also in game voice comms and text chat (very hard to use while driving, so not recommended).

You need to have the same DLC maps as the server though.